Настройки запуска python manage.py из VSCode через файл launch.json
Структура проекта

Задаю наcтройки запуска Python программы в VSCode


В предыдущем скриншоте выбираю Django. А затем выбираю manage.py

Чтобы не использовать команду
python manage.py runserver

а пользоваться кнопкой со стрелкой в правом верхнем углу.
В предложенных опциях есть только Python Debugger, несмотря на то что установлены расширения Python, Pylance, Django, Black Formatter. Установленные пакеты см. на скриншоте снизу

И в результате получаю следующий настроечный файл запуска
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Django",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "autoStartBrowser": false
        }
    ]
}

В результате программу можно запускать только в режиме отладки Start Debugging (F5).
d:\dev_env\app> d: && cd d:\dev_env\app && cmd /C "d:\dev_env\venv\Scripts\python.exe c:\Users\hpweb\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher 54334 -- D:\dev_env\app\manage.py runserver "
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
May 26, 2024 - 16:10:31
Django version 4.2.7, using settings 'app.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

При запуске через Run Without Debugging выдает
d:\dev_env\app> d: && cd d:\dev_env\app && cmd /C "d:\dev_env\venv\Scripts\python.exe c:\Users\hpweb\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher 54324 -- d:\dev_env\app\manage.py "

Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[auth]
    changepassword
    createsuperuser

[contenttypes]
    remove_stale_contenttypes

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    optimizemigration
    sendtestemail
    shell
    showmigrations
    sqlflush
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    test
    testserver

[sessions]
    clearsessions

[staticfiles]
    collectstatic
    findstatic
    runserver

Как надо изменить настройки, чтобы можно было осуществлять запуск программы без отладки?
Файл .vscode/settings.json имеет вид
{
    "git.autoRepositoryDetection": "subFolders",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,

    "debug.autoExpandLazyVariables": true,
    "debug.inlineValues": "on",

    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "off",
    "python.analysis.diagnosticMode": "openFilesOnly",
    "python.analysis.autoSearchPaths": true,
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
    "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
    "python.analysis.inlayHints.variableTypes": true,
    "python.analysis.inlayHints.functionReturnTypes": true,
    "python.analysis.importFormat": "absolute",
    "python.analysis.enablePytestSupport": true,
    "python.analysis.indexing": true,
    "python.analysis.packageIndexDepths": [
        {
            "name": "django",
            "depth": 3,
            "includeAllSymbols": true
        }
    ],
      
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "django-html": "html"
    },
    "files.associations": {
        "**/*.html": "html",
        "**/templates/*/*.html": "django-html",
        "**/templates/*/*/*.html": "django-html",
        "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
        "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
    },
    "django.snippets.exclude": [
        "cms",
        "wagtail"
    ],


    "[django-html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "batisteo.vscode-django",
        "breadcrumbs.showClasses": true,
        "editor.quickSuggestions": {
            "other": true,
            "comments": true,
            "strings": true
        }
    }
}

Пытался

но подчеркнуло
"type": "python",
"autoStartBrowser": false

.
В результате выдало
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3593]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

(venv) D:\dev_env> cmd /C "d:\dev_env\venv\Scripts\python.exe c:\Users\hpweb\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher 63021 -- D:\dev_env\app\manage.py "

Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[auth]
    changepassword
    createsuperuser

[contenttypes]
    remove_stale_contenttypes

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    optimizemigration
    sendtestemail
    shell
    showmigrations
    sqlflush
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    test
    testserver

[sessions]
    clearsessions

[staticfiles]
    collectstatic
    findstatic
    runserver

(venv) D:\dev_env>

Пытался также
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django runserver",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\app\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}

но выдало то же самое, что и в последний раз.
